# NullReferenceException adding XElement To An XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to add dynamically elements to a root using LINQ, it was working before. But it returns  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". 
It only works creating the new XElement instance manually.

```
try  
{
   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(_documentName);
   XElement _newElements = new XElement(_rowName);

   foreach(string s in _commaSeparatedNameValues)
   {
       _newElements.Add(new XElement( s.Split(',')[0], s.Split(',')[1]));
   }

   xdoc.Element(_rowName).Add(_newElements);
   xdoc.Save(_documentName);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   string s = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: Which line gets the exception? And don't use try/catch that way - it  hides errors.

Comment: Catch the exception and look at the stack trace to find out which line actually threw the exception.  Then inspect that line and find out why something is null on that line at any given point in the program.

Comment: xdoc.Element(_rowName).Add(_newElements); it doesnt return null objec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(_documentName);       
XElement _newElements = new XElement(_rowName);
...
xdoc.Element(_rowName).Add(_newElements);
```

You never add _newElements to xdoc, so `xdoc.Element(_rowName)` will be `null`.
And otherwiser it would have been an attempt to add an element to itself.

The fix, untested:

```
//xdoc.Element(_rowName).Add(_newElements);
xdoc.Add(_newElements);
```

or more probably:

```
xdoc.Root.Add(_newElements);
```

Comment: Well, manually it works int his way:  XElement _newElements = new XElement(_rowName, new Xelement...); but in my current scenario i must do it dinamically...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have to build the xml dynamically. May be the question is other. I understand.

Comment: xdoc.Root.Add(_newElements);
It works! Thanks i spent 4 hours, im newbie using linq and xml. :D